# number_to_human with currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using number_to_human to print 4 Million. I was wondering if there is a method that will add the $ to the front of the number? 
I run into issues when I have a negative number. 
If I just throw a $ in front I will get $-4 Million they want -$4 Million

Comment: don't forget to accept one answer, it's part of the game here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's builtin Rails:

```
number_to_currency(number_to_human(-4000000))
# => "-$4 Million"
```

The big advantage in using convention is that, when you need i18n, you just have to pass the locale:

```
number_to_currency(number_to_human(-4000000), locale: 'en-EU')
# => "-4 Million €"
```

Comment: Thanks I think I had the reverse.

Answer (score 8):

Its interesting thing and If It would help to anybody:

```
How to Present thousands as "K", millions as "M" in ruby for that, 
just follow the steps
```

Include NumberHelper in controller at top

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

Use this number_to_human Helper and pass the value, This will convert the value

```
<%= number_to_human(5223654) %>
```

Paste this code in en.yml to get it working

```
en:
  number:
    human:
      decimal_units:
       format: "%n%u"
       units:
         unit: ""
         thousand: K
         million: M
         billion: B
         trillion: T
         quadrillion: Q
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be better ways. however, here is a quick hack

```
amount = -4000000
if amount < 0
  human = "-$#{number_to_human(amount.abs)}"
else
  human = "$#{number_to_human(amount)}"
end
```

@apneadiving shows the real simple ways.